# Citation for Silverlight 4 backward compatibility?

Tags: silverlight-4.0, silverlight-3.0, backwards-compatibility

I have a strong impression that the Silverlight 4 client runtime will run a Silverlight 3 application perfectly well, but for the life of me I can't find a definitive statement from Microsoft to that effect.

Can anyone provide a reference?

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few citations. Here's one from Tim Heuer, the Silverlight PM.

http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2010/04/15/silverlight-4-breaking-changes-backward-compatibility.aspx

> Yes, this is the situation we refer to
>   as backward compatibility.  What this
>   means is that existing compiled XAPs
>   under previous versions should
>   continue to work as-is even if your
>   users have a later version of
>   Silverlight installed on their
>   machine.

And from a Microsoft website, in a section that seems like it doesn't really apply (but it does):
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc265156(VS.95).aspx

> ...each major version of the
>   Silverlight plug-in. Each version is
>   backward compatible with the previous
>   versions.

And another:
http://support.microsoft.com/gp/lifean45

> Microsoft will continue to support all
>   versions of Silverlight by shipping
>   updates to the latest version of both
>   Silverlight runtime and Silverlight
>   SDK. Updates and new versions of the
>   Silverlight runtime are backward
>   compatible with web applications built
>   in previous versions of Silverlight
>   and will include the latest security
>   enhancements, performance
>   improvements, and product fixes.